# How to have scalable widgets in Tkinter?

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

**Question**

I have created several GUI projects so far, but they all have one fatal mistake. When I make a   window smaller, (which usually uses only one `frame.`) several of the widgets will disappear. Is there anyway to make the widgets 'aware' of the size of their frame?

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried to use this:

```
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
```

to specify the size of the window, but since many widgets use values other than pixels, it never works. I am also unsure as to whether it updates constantly or only when the window is spawned. (`Text` uses the size of the characters... etc)

**Specs**

Python 2.7.3

Windows 7/ Mac OSX Lion

Answer (score 0):

This is generally quite easy, and often just happens by default. It all depends on how you use `pack` and `grid`. Without seeing your code it's going to be hard to give you useful information.

Can you show us a really small program that illustrates the problem and is an accurate indication of how you lay out your GUIs?